# Can I override a column's value in Select CASE SQL

Tags: sql, case

Can I override a value in a column such that if a case is true, it tells value x to be equal to another dynamic value in the query.  Here's pseudocode. I know this doesn't work.

```
Select jobTitle, managerTitle, bigBossTitle,
    CASE WHEN jobtitle like '%DEVELOP%' THEN managerTitle = bigBossTitle
    END 
From PeopleTable
inner join... other tables...
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select     
    jobTitle, 
      CASE WHEN jobtitle like '%DEVELOP%' 
      THEN bigBossTitle 
      ELSE managerTitle 
      END as managerTitle, 
    bigBossTitle,

From PeopleTable
inner join... other tables...
```

You just put the case statement where the managerTitle column was and then alias the result as managerTitle. This logic effectively gives you what you're looking for. To actually "replace" a value you would need to do more advanced T-SQL and it's not really necessary.

**Example of using a case statement in a join predicate:**

```
...
inner join otherTable 
on otherTable.bossTitle = 
      CASE WHEN jobtitle like '%DEVELOP%' 
      THEN bigBossTitle 
      ELSE managerTitle 
      END
```

Comment: Cheers.  I am giving that a go now.

Comment: I am very close mate.  At the end of a quite long query I have the inner join where I now need the new value of managerTitle to join to another table.  inner join table2 on table2 = managerTitle.  Is that possible?

Comment: @Sean: Yes it's possible. In its simplest form just use the case statement in your join predicate/clause but drop the alias `as managerTitle`)

Comment: @Sean: I updated the answer to include an example of using a case statement in a join predicate.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, Paul.  I appreciate it.  I will try that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Select jobTitle,
    CASE
        WHEN jobtitle like '%DEVELOP%'
        THEN bigBossTitle
        ELSE managerTitle 
    END as managerTitle,
   bigBossTitle
From PeopleTable
inner join... other tables...
```

Answer (score 1):

You were very close. Your `CASE` would be like this:

```
Select jobTitle, bigBossTitle,
    CASE 
          WHEN jobtitle like '%DEVELOP%' 
          THEN bigBossTitle 
          ELSE managerTitle
    END as managerTitle
From PeopleTable
inner join... other tables...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that :

```
Select jobTitle, managerTitle, bigBossTitle, IF(jobtitle like '%DEVELOP%', bigBossTitle, OTHER_VALUE_IF_FALSE) AS managerTitle 
From PeopleTable
inner join... other tables...
```